# Google shows wrong results for site domain search

Tags: google, google-search

I entered site:example.com on google search it gave me list of unique pages exists on my website, and then I selected 'Past Week' filter under 'Show search tools' it gives me just 4 results when I have more then 50 posts from past one week.

Sitemap.xml is submitted as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible that those pages have not (yet) been indexed. Try a Google search for `site:www.example.com/canonical/url` to see if one of the missing pages is indeed in Google's index.

Submitting an XML sitemap is not a guarantee that those pages will be indexed - it is simply a recommendation.

If you look in Google's Webmaster Tools it should tell you (from your Sitemap) how many URLs have been submitted and how many have been indexed.

Comment: +1 A site-limited search is not a reliable way to determine how many URLs have been indexed for your site; it only shows you a selection. This is what Webmaster Tools is for.

Comment: I tried Google search as eg: site:www.example.com/canonical/url I see the page in results. but the same dose not show up when 'Past Week' is clicked.

Comment: As Su' mentions, a `site:` search is not necessarily reliable and all results may not be shown. Another point is how Google has determined the publish date (or _last updated date_ (?) if looking at the advanced search page) of the page. Other dates that appear on page can affect this.

Comment: dose the change frequency which is mentioned on the sitmap.xml  matters on the results as well?

Comment: An XML sitemap is advisory, not authoritative. Google _might_ use the `<changefreq>` to determine crawl rates, but it might not (probably not IMO). It _might_ use the `<lastmod>` as a factor in determining the last modified date of the page - but it certainly uses other metrics as well. I have a site where Google has picked up an arbitrary date that appears near the top of the page as the publish date of the page - it is not - and this differs from the `<lastmod>` date specified in the XML sitemap.

Comment: See also this page which discusses how Google determines the publish date of a page/post... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/how-does-google-recognize-publish-date-of-a-post

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear information, It was really helpful for me.